# Taking over a C# project, with dreaded "These Projects are not Supported"

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015

I took over a C# project from someone who I don't have access to.  There's no documentation on dependencies, and I don't know anything about their development environment.

In Visual Studio 2015, when I open the project, I get this window

[image]

I remember in the past, I just opened the .csproj file, and looked at the `<ProjectTypeGuids>`, googled those, and got what it said.  However, this project only has two listed, and that step hasn't done anything for me.  Here are

my Guids `<ProjectTypeGuids>{BAA0C2D2-18E2-41B9-852F-F413020CAA33};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>`

So, it was obviously **C#**, and used **Visual Studio Tools for Office**.  I have both of those, and I'm on the correct version of .NET, I'm pretty sure.  I'm using 4.5.2, and have lots of other installed. Here's the first few lines of the .csproj file

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />`

Other things I've tried:

- Adding references for `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook`, as well as the Core.
- Pressing the button provided by Microsoft that says **Install Missing Features**.  Yes, I did laugh as a pressed it.
- The obvious "Reload Project"
- A few other really small things that I don't think are the problem, that others on SO have said they had issues with, like closing all files, and trying to build etc...

I'm not incredibly experienced with VS, or C#, but I've done a bit.  Can anyone tell me what the next step in troubleshooting is?

Comment: It might be fastest to create a new project, add the files and references until it compiles. You can then compare the project files in a div tool and see what was wrong.

Comment: It's not a massive project, so I'm sure you're right.  I may end up doing that, but I am interested in what the next steps would be.  It's not uncommon for me to get old projects after someone has left, and I've had this problem every single time.  Obviously we need to do a better job keeping our dev environments standardized, but this seems to be a pretty silly issue that lots of people have regularly.

Comment: I've also had these kind of issues and you're right, the situation is less than optimal. That's why you should compare the project files at the end.

Comment: What edition of VS2015 are you using? It is possible that the original solution/project was created with a higher version/edition of VS2015.

Comment: That would make a lot of sense.  I quickly downloaded their new Visual Studio Community 2015.  It's very possible that he was using pro.

Comment: I think VSTO is not supported in Community.

Comment: Kudos to Microsoft for making such a clear, elaborate, and useful error message, letting us know exactly what's wrong with the project.